# html php utf8 encoding

Tags: php, html, encoding

I have hopefully an easily resolved problem.

I have set up a test php page on my sever with the following code:

```html
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo "£";

?>
```

However when I re-open the file to edit the symbol 'Ã' is appended to the £ symbol. An additional 'Ã' is appended each time I open the script.

```html
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo "Â£";

?>
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: This has nothing to do with php, html or http. It simply is a question of your local systems setup. Obviously the editor uses different encodings. You should first take care to reconfigure your local system such that it actually uses UTF-8. That is nothing you can somehow reach by php code or a header entry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)